# Usage of PHP to encrypt

Tags: php, string, encryption, key, encode

I want to encrypt the content of an entire PHP file.
I found this , searching around :

```
$key = 'password to (en/de)crypt';  
$string = ' string to be encrypted '; // note the spaces
```

To encrypt :

```
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), 
                           $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
```

I want to use exactly the same method but I don't know how.
And do I need to remove the  tags of the file ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `file_get_contents()` the read the file, store it in `$string`, encrypt it and then write it to disk again using `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: Do I need to remove the <?php , ?> tags from it ?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to accomplish I guess. If you simply read a PHP file from disk, encrypt it, and write it back, then you do not. The PHP code will not be parsed or run in this case. The file contents might as well be text, binary data or incomplete/erroneous PHP code in the file your encrypting - your script will not know the difference. Note also that the encrypted PHP source of course will not run, since it's simply encrypted data and not PHP code.